# What is the best way to operate with time in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am developing an Android app using **Kotlin** and I would like to achieve the following:

1. Let a user select a time for an alert (hh:mm) from current time until the following 24 hours
    *e.g. at 16:00 user wants to put an alert for tomorrow at 15:00.*
2. Once the user has set the alert, I want to show the time remaining until the alert is activated (hh:mm)
    *e.g. Show a small dialog with the text: 3h:15min remaining.*

**What is the best way to deal with time operations (subtract current time to the alert time) in Kotlin?**

Comment: [I feel like i answered  very similar question before...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434240/make-timer-count-from-date/53434392#53434392)

Comment: It looks like that, yes. But I were looking for (maybe It wasn't clear in my question) the best way to handle this situation in the most kotlin idiomatic way (and to know if already exists a way to handle it, and if it is not deprecated, as `Date` from `Java.util` is).

I read you answer to that question before asking it here, but it didn't answer my question.

Thanks a lot for answering :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your questions have been asked and answered many times on Stack Overflow. So I’ll be brief. Search to learn more.

Use only *java.time* classes, never  the terrible legacy classes such as `Date` and `Calendar`.

For Android before 26, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* library and its Android-specific wrapper *ThreeTenABP*.

Represent a time-of-day with `LocalTime`.

```
LocalTime targetLocalTime = LocalTime.of( 15 , 0 ) ;
```

Get current moment. Requires a time zone. 2-4 letter codes like `CST` are not real time zones. Real zones are named `Continent/Region`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Compare time portion. Extract a `LocalTime` to compare.

```
Boolean runToday = now.toLocalTime().isBefore( targetLocalTime ) ;
```

Determining next alarm time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = now.with( targetLocalTime ) ;
```

Or if needed on next day, tomorrow.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = now.toLocalDate().plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ).with( targetLocalTime ) ;
```

Calculate elapsed time. Adjust to UTC by extracting an `Instant`.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( now.toInstant() , zdt.toInstant() ) ;
```

Generate string in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = d.toString() ;
```

Or generate a string in another format by calling the `Duration::to…Part` methods.

As for firing the alarm, in straight Java use the *Executors* framework, specifically `ScheduledExecutorService`. This framework makes it simple to run a background thread that fires a task `Runnable` at a certain moment. Well, nearly certain — slight delays may occur for garbage-collection or thread/process scheduling on the CPU, but good enough for business apps (not good enough for NASA).

Android may also provide some alarm-setting feature. (I don’t know)

Never ever access or manipulate your user-interface from a background thread. Use whatever hook Android provides to update the UI from another thread, such as refreshing a UI widget or presenting a notification.

Comment: your first paragraph should not be part of the answer. this is more like a comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

According to *Basil Bourque*, the following is the code he proposed (in Java) converted to Kotlin, just in case someone is interested.

```
// Credit to Basil Bourque Answer
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846004/what-is-the-best-way-to-operate-with-time-in-kotlin/59846550#59846550

lateinit var zdt: ZonedDateTime
val targetLocaltime = LocalTime.of(21, 0)
val z = ZoneId.of("Europe/Madrid")
val now = ZonedDateTime.now(z)
val runToday = now.toLocalTime().isBefore(targetLocaltime)

zdt = if (runToday){
    now.with(targetLocaltime)
}
else{
    now.toLocalDate().plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(z).with(targetLocaltime)
}
val eta = Duration.between(now.toInstant(), zdt.toInstant()).toMinutes()
if(eta > 60){
    val hours = eta / 60
    val minutes = eta % 60
    print("$hours:$minutes remaining")
}
else{
    print("$eta minutes remaining")
}
```